# Cambiar el tamaño de un TextView de Android con el tacto, acercando y alejando los dedos (Pinch Zoom)

Tags: android

Tengo un `TextView` en mi App al cual quiero dar la posibilidad de que el usuario agrande o disminuya el tamaño del texto acercando o alejando con dos dedos (pinch zoom).

He instalado la librería [`PinchZoomTextView`](https://github.com/androidessence/PinchZoomTextView) para tales fines.

Funciona más o menos bien, sólo que, cuando pruebo en mi dispositivo, al tratar de ampliar con los dedos, **lo primero que hace es ponerme el texto más pequeño de lo que está,** y entonces a partir de ahí, tengo que seguir separando los dedos  para agrandar...

Es un poco desagradable:

1. Cuando intento agrandar el texto lo que hace es que lo pone más pequeño
2. Tengo que hacer varios movimientos para llegar al tamaño original del texto
3. Y a partir de ahí seguir agrandando.

Para evitar eso, le di un tamaño mínimo al `TextView`: `android:autoSizeMinTextSize="25sp"`, pero aún así, lo lleva a un tamaño pequeño. Es como si lo llevara al tamaño estándar para empezar a agrandar.

La app está destinada a personas de una cierta edad que no tiene demasiada práctica en informática, por lo que este comportamiento será sin duda una mala experiencia de usuario.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de mejorar eso en dicha librería o si conocen alguna otra librería que pueda usar, o algún método adecuado para aumentar/disminuir el tamaño del texto acercando alejando con los dos dedos.

Este es el código:

#### layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.androidessence.pinchzoomtextview.PinchZoomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_breviario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

#### activity

No tiene más historia, es texto obtenido de un servicio REST.

```
final PinchZoomTextView mTextView = (PinchZoomTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_breviario);
String strTexto = showTercia(response);
strContenido = Utils.fromHtml(strTexto);
mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(strTexto.replaceAll(SEPARADOR, "")));
```

Comment: enviale un issues que tenga en cuenta el atributo android:autoSizeMinTextSize